# Is there a way to see if a GRID layout has responsively collapsed to just one column?

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

I am getting into GRID and FLEX and trying very hard to abandon just DIVS with floats.

Does anyone know if there is a way to determine (JQUERY is fine) if a GRID layout has collapsed into just one column?  If I can tell this, then I can do things like CENTER it (which I wouldn't want to do if it was one of 6 columns) or turn off hover effects (which wouldn't really be necessary and are pretty ugly when there's only 1 choice/1 column).

I am not looking for a media query on screen width; but rather a way to factually see if its one column or not, regardless of screen width.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks if the grid has collapsed into a single column by comparing the vertical positions of the first two grid items. If their `offsetTop` values are different, it means they are on different rows, indicating a single-column layout.

```
function checkSingleColumnGrid(gridItemSelector) {
    var gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(gridItemSelector);
    if (gridItems.length < 2) {
        // not enough grid items to determine the layout
        return false;
    }
    var firstItem = gridItems[0];
    var secondItem = gridItems[1];
    return firstItem.offsetTop !== secondItem.offsetTop; // compare vertical position
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (checkSingleColumnGrid('.grid-container > div')) {
        // single column
    } else {
        // multiple columns
    }
});
```

Comment: YES YES YES!  This works PERFECTLY.   Thank you much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the child width matches the parents width:

```js
  const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
  const isSingleColumn = grid.offsetWidth === grid.firstElementChild?.offsetWidth;
```

Only works when you have no alignment though.